# Delphi function generic

Tags: function, delphi, generics

I would like to create a generic function. I'm novice in generic.
I've 3 private lists of different type. I want a public generic method for return 1 item of the list.

I've the code below. (I have it simplifie)

```
TFilter = class
private
   FListFilter            : TObjectList<TFilterEntity>;
   FListFilterDate        : TObjectList<TFilterDate>;
   FListFilterRensParam   : TObjectList<TFilterRensParam>;
public
   function yGetFilter<T>(iIndice : integer) : T; 
....
function TFilter .yGetFilter<T>(iIndice : integer) : T; 
begin
    if T = TFilterEntity then
       result := T(FListFilter.Items[iIndice])
    else
       ....
end;
```

I know that code doesn't run, but can you tell me if it's possible to do a thing that it ?

Comment: This looks like a weak use of generics. Any time you have to include a runtime type test that often means the design is poor. I suspect that you can do better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just introduce a [constraint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics#Class_Type_Constraints) of the generic parameter `T`. It has to be a class.

From the documentation:

> A type parameter may be constrained by zero or one class type. As with interface type constraints, this declaration means that the compiler will require any concrete type passed as an argument to the constrained type param to be assignment compatible with the constraint class.
>   Compatibility of class types follows the normal rules of OOP type compatibilty - descendent types can be passed where their ancestor types are required.

Change declaration to:

```
function yGetFilter<T:class>(iIndice : integer) : T;
```

---

Update

It appears that in XE5 and earlier you get a compiler error:

> E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

at this line:

```
if T = TFilterEntity then
```

In XE6 and above this bug is fixed.

To circumvent, do as David says in a comment:

```
if TClass(T) = TFilterEntity then
```

Comment: Are you sure that a constraint of function it's similar that a constraint of class ? I've this error : [dcc32 Erreur] YP.Filter.ListFilter.pas(307): E2029 ',', ';' ou '>' attendu(e) mais ':' trouvé(e)

Comment: +1 but you need an extra cast `if TClass(T) = TFilterEntity then` to make the compiler happy

Comment: Now the compilator is happy ! Thank you

Comment: I also get E2029 ',', ';' or '>' expected but ':' found. In my case it is not clear to me where to place an extra cast.