# Cannot compile constrained generic method

Tags: delphi, generics, constraints, delphi-10.1-berlin, generic-constraints

Long story short: The following piece of code does not compile in *Delphi 10.1 Berlin (Update 2)*.

```
interface

uses
  System.Classes, System.SysUtils;

type
  TTest = class(TObject)
  public
    function BuildComponent<T: TComponent>(const AComponentString: String): T;
  end;

  TSomeComponent = class(TComponent)
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; const AString: String); reintroduce;
  end;

implementation

{ TTest }

function TTest.BuildComponent<T>(const AComponentString: String): T;
begin
  if T = TSomeComponent then
    Result := TSomeComponent.Create(nil, AComponentString)
  else
    Result := T.Create(nil);
end;

{ TSomeComponent }

constructor TSomeComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent; const AString: String);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;
```

Several error messages are emitted from the compiler:

1. > E2015: Operator not applicable to this operand type

   on line `if T = TSomeComponent then` and
2. > E2010 Incompatible types - 'T' and 'TSomeComponent'

   on line `Result := TSomeComponent.Create(nil, AComponentString)`.

To circumvent these, I could cast `TClass(T)` (for #1), as described in [*LU RD*'s answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26115578/4236400) (despite it is said, that this bug has already been fixed in *XE6*), and `T(TSomeComponent.Create(nil, AComponentString))`(for #2). Although, I feel uncomfortable using explicit type-casting.

**Is there any better way? Shouldn't the compiler recognize, that `T` is of type `TComponent` because I constrained it explicitly?**

---

At first, I tried to declare the generic function's implementation like it's interface:

```
function TTest.BuildComponent<T: TComponent>(const AComponentString: String): T;
```

But this ended up with the error

> E2029: ',', ';' or '>' expected but ':' found

Comment: "Shouldn't the compiler recognize, that T is of type TComponent because I constrained it explicitly?"   No, it won't.  A generic constraint does not resolve type.  It simply helps the compiler *prevent* using the generic type or procedure with types other than those of the constraint.  See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679740/test-if-an-interface-equals-a-type-parameter/43681952#43681952

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not compile in any version of Delphi that I have encountered. You need to do some casting to persuade the compiler to compile this:

```
function TTest.BuildComponent<T>(const AComponentString: String): T;
begin
  if TClass(T) = TSomeComponent then
    Result := T(TSomeComponent.Create(nil, AComponentString))
  else
    Result := T(TComponentClass(T).Create(nil));
end;
```

That said, I think that I might prefer:

```
if TClass(T).InheritsFrom(TSomeComponent) then
```

in place of that equality test.

Even then, trying to splice in a new constructor with different arguments, to a class based on a virtual constructor looks like a recipe for disaster to me.

Comment: I would prefer the `InheritsFrom` test too. And indeed, I would not give the new component a different constructor. I would use properties instead. And then, the BuildComponent would probably not have to be generic anymore, he could just pass a TComponentClass (and perhaps an owner). Or perhaps he could do completely without it.